# How can I refill a buffer when the data in the buffer is being checked in C?

Tags: c, file-io, buffer

In this code, a buffer of length 1000 will be checked for the occurence of a particular word. And the next checking starts from the 1001th position. If the search word lies across the 998th position or something, the word will be ignored. I would like to know how can I refill the buffer while the contents of the buffer is checked. How can I do double buffering in this problem so that no extra memory is used and the program is faster?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fptr;
    int l, count = 0, index;
    char name[100], word[25], buffer[1000], *pos;
    printf("\nEnter the word to be found:");
    scanf("%s", word);
    l = strlen(word);
    printf("\nEnter the file name:");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fptr = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("\nProblem with opening the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((fgets(buffer, 1000, fptr)) != NULL) {
        index = 0;
        while ((pos = strstr(buffer + index, word)) != NULL) {
            index = (pos - buffer) + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("The word %s is found %d times", word, count);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use multiple buffers without using more memory, and you cannot avoid the I/O latency without another thread or an event-driven async design. 'faster', 'no extra memory' are usually mutually exclusive:(  Given your need to span buffers while searching, I would probably not use strstr() and work.byte-by-byte myself.

Comment: I mean, you can mess around with two buffers and strstr if you want to, memcpying the incompletely-searched bytes from the end of one buffer to the start of the other and topping it up from disk. I would not do it but, hey, it's your design:)

Comment: @MartinJames thanks brother. Would you suggest me a better algorithm for the above code? It's okay if it consumes some extra memory.

Comment: *In this code, a buffer of length 1000 will be checked for the occurence of a particular word. And the next checking starts from the 1001th position.*  That's not what the code does.  It reads *lines* **up to** 998 (need space for the terminating `'\0'`) characters per line, not counting the `'\n'` newline separating each line.  If a line has 999 or more non-`'\n'` characters, it will be split into multiple buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Your program searches for all occurrences of the string in the file, line by line.

For example the string `aa` is present 3 times in the line `aaaa`. Is this the intended behavior?

If the file has very long lines that get read in pieces by `fgets()`, you could still get the correct count by copying the end of the buffer to the start of the buffer and read the next part after that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fptr;
    int len, count, index, overlap;
    char name[100], word[25], buffer[100];
    char *pos;

    printf("Enter the word to be found: ");
    if (scanf("%24s", word) != 1)
        return 1;
    len = strlen(word);
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", name) != 1)
        return 1;
    fptr = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Problem with opening the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    overlap = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer + overlap, sizeof(buffer) - overlap, fptr) != NULL) {
        index = 0;
        while ((pos = strstr(buffer + index, word)) != NULL) {
            index = (pos - buffer) + 1;
            count++;
        }
        overlap = 0;
        if (strlen(buffer) == sizeof(buffer) - 1 && buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 2] != '\n') {
            // line was split
            memmove(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - len, len);
            overlap = len - 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The word %s is found %d times\n", word, count);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```